# Smart Home device implementing Alexa.Speaker Interface not responding to volume change request

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My [Alexa Smart Home Skill for Entertainment Devices](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/building-smart-home-skills-for-entertainment-devices) implements a few capabilities of API version 3, including the [Alexa.Speaker Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-speaker).

As far as I understand from the documentation, it should respond to voice commands such as *“Alexa, set the volume of device to 5”*, however Alexa always responds with *"Sorry, I can't control the volume on your device"*.

The discovery response of the device looks like this

```
{
    endpointId: 'music1',
    friendlyName: 'pillow',
    description: 'Music on Kodi',
    manufacturerName: 'Cubox-i',
    displayCategories: [],
    capabilities: [
        {
            type: 'AlexaInterface',
            interface: 'Alexa.PowerController',
            version: '1.0',
            properties: {
                supported: [
                    {
                        name: 'powerState',
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
        {
            type: 'AlexaInterface',
            interface: 'Alexa.PlaybackController',
            version: '1.0',
            properties: {},
        },
        {
            type: 'AlexaInterface',
            interface: 'Alexa.Speaker',
            version: '1.0',
            properties: {
                supported: [
                    {
                        name: 'volume',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'muted',
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

The discovery seems to work fine, as the `PowerController` interface is being responded to fine (e.g. *"Alexa, turn on pillow"*).
I can see discovery, `PowerController` and `PlaybackController` requests and responses in the AWS Lambda logs.

Any voice commands to `Speaker` (whether trying to set the volume *to 20*, increasing it *by 5*, or asking to *mute* or *unmute* pillow) do not produce any requests to my Lambda and result in the response mentioned above – or in the case of muting in *"Pillow doesn't support that"*.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
properties: {
            supported: [
                {
                    name: 'volume',
                },
                {
                    name: 'muted',
                },
            ],
        },
```

this JSON ,use this:

```
'properties.supported':[{
                    name: 'volume',
                },
                {
                    name: 'muted',
                }]
```

This is a bug they are trying to solve,but till then,this will work,please let me know if this particular solution works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems to have done the trick for the "mute/unmute" command. However when trying to set the volume ("Set the volume of pillow to 5”), the response is still "Sorry, I can't control the volume on your device" – or sometimes "Sorry, pillow doesn't support that".

What's funny here is that even though I use the same input command, the error message is sometimes the one and sometimes the other. Combined with your hint, this tells me this API is not that stable yet and the error might not be on mine but on Amazon's side.

Answer (score 2):

To addition to 'properties.supported' the **version should be 1** (not 3). The Speaker interface discovery response should look like:

```
{   
    "type": "AlexaInterface",
    "interface": "Alexa.Speaker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "properties.supported":[
    {
        "name": "muted",
    },
    {
        "name": "volume"
    }]
}
```